# SAGA-GIS 2.3.1 Segmentation Fault on launch

Tags: qgis, installation, error, saga, arch-linux

I recently installed QGIS, GRASS, and SAGA-GIS-LTR onto a Manjaro (Arch Linux-based) system in order to make use of their newer libraries. While most of the software is working fine I did need to perform a workaround for GRASS to make use of the newest libraries such as GDAL (e.g. creating a symlink pointing to the newest version `ln -s libgdal.so.13 libgdal.so.12`).

Using the Arch User Repository, I installed SAGA-GIS-LTR and it seems to be recogized/callable from QGIS 3.0.2. Unfortunately, none of the algorithms have been working. SAGA will run the processes, signify that there's an output file and then crash without a stacktrace in the QGIS processing window.

I checked into it further and found that in my terminal the `saga_cmd` tools have a segfault and core dump on launch. The `gdb` (gnu debugger) stack trace is as follows:

```
   #####   ##   #####    ##
  ###     ###  ##       ###
   ###   # ## ##  #### # ##
    ### ##### ##    # #####
 ##### #   ##  ##### #   ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.3.1


Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff6c491e6 in __strlen_sse2 () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6c491e6 in __strlen_sse2 () at /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff6c619c4 in __mbsrtowcs_l () at /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7687b6f in wxMB2WC(wchar_t*, char const*, unsigned long) () 
at /usr/lib/libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff7633b25 in wxMBConv::ToWChar(wchar_t*, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) const () at /usr/lib/libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff76344b0 in wxMBConv::cMB2WC(char const*, unsigned long,unsigned long*) const () at /usr/lib/libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0
#5  0x00007ffff764402e in wxString::ConvertStr(char const*, unsigned long, wxMBConv const&) () at /usr/lib/libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0
#6  0x0000555555560b0d in wxString::ImplStr(char const*, wxMBConv const&) ()
#7  0x0000555555560c43 in wxString::wxString(char const*) ()
#8  0x00007ffff7a493cb in CSG_String::CSG_String(char const*) ()
at /usr/lib/libsaga_api-2.3.1.so
#9  0x00007fffe64b3cf4 in CPROJ4_Base::_Init_Projection(CSG_Parameters&) ()
at /usr/lib/saga/libpj_proj4.so
#10 0x00007fffe64ae9a5 in CPROJ4_Base::CPROJ4_Base(int, bool) ()
at /usr/lib/saga/libpj_proj4.so
#11 0x00007fffe64be02a in CPROJ4_Shapes::CPROJ4_Shapes(int, bool) ()
at /usr/lib/saga/libpj_proj4.so
#12 0x00007fffe647ce3b in Create_Module(int) () at /usr/lib/saga/libpj_proj4.so
#13 0x00007fffe647d27b in MLB_Initialize () at /usr/lib/saga/libpj_proj4.so
#14 0x00007ffff7ad7cc6 in CSG_Module_Library::CSG_Module_Library(CSG_String const&) () at /usr/lib/libsaga_api-2.3.1.so
#15 0x00007ffff7ad9e66 in CSG_Module_Library_Manager::Add_Library(wchar_t const*) () at /usr/lib/libsaga_api-2.3.1.so
#16 0x00007ffff7ada341 in CSG_Module_Library_Manager::Add_Directory(wchar_t const*, bool) () at /usr/lib/libsaga_api-2.3.1.so
#17 0x0000555555562e3a in  ()
#18 0x0000555555562f17 in  ()
#19 0x0000555555561e3c in  ()
#20 0x0000555555561cd3 in  ()
#21 0x00007ffff6bd506b in __libc_start_main () at /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#22 0x000055555555b17a in  ()
```

I'm wodnering where the issue is. Was SAGA-GIS-LTR not compiled properly? Am I missing specific libraries? Is this the result of a known bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a widespread issue with saga ltr on newer gcc compiler versions. It needs to be fixed by the saga team. There's no workaround that I'm aware of.

Comment: You should check whether the latest branch fixes the issue - it did on debian. https://github.com/johanvdw/SAGA-gis-git-mirror/commits/release-2-3-lts

Comment: This new build ended up fixing the issue for me. Thanks developer-peeps!